# Why am I getting an "IndentationError - expected an indented block after 'if' statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements, indentation

[Screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVzyk.png)

I am in the very early stages of learning conditional statements in python. I am trying to create an "if" statement with the following code.

```
flag = True
if flag == True:
    print("yay!")
```

However, whenever I try to run the code, I just keep getting the "IndentionError - expected an indented block after 'if' statement". Is there something that I am missing? The code shows an indentation after the 'if' statement.

I have read other similar prompts from stack overflow, however not sure if I just cant find a solution to my issue or I have missed it but I would appreciate any insight to my problem.

Comment: Is there more code? There's no indentation error in those three lines in isolation.

Comment: That is all the code. However, the full error message is:                File "<stdin>", line 2
    
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block after 'if' statement on line 1. Does the top part of the message have anything to do with why my code is not running?

Comment: It maybe a problem with the text editor too, could you upload a screenshot of the code as well?

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot of my code. Let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: According to the screenshot, the code that caused the error is in the "Terminal" window of that application, which is **not** the code you posted here.

Comment: I believe the problem is you are executing the code in Interactive Mode i.e. executing the code line by line. Executing it all at once should fix the problem. Try using that `Play` button in the top right to execute your code

Comment: That worked. Thanks for bearing with me, I appreciate yalls help. I am very much a beginner with all of this stuff, so this was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Taking the code and directly copy/pasting it into Visual Studio I didn't get any errors. I would agree with @KillerRebooted that it may be a text editor issue. You could try closing the text editor, then retyping it into a new file and see if that make a difference, but your code is correct! Best of luck!